# Alternative solution to handle com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER for Android 8.0 (API level 26)

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-developer-api

As part of the Android 8.0 (API level 26) Background Execution Limits, apps that target the API level 26 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest.

So what could be the alternative solutions for Android 8.0 (API level 26) to support com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER [The Google Play com.android .vending.INSTALL_REFERRER Intent is broadcast when an app is installed from the Google Play Store.]

Comment: Actually I ran one of my old application which has reciever INSTALL_REFERRER, but for some reason InstallReceiver was not getting invoked. Here is the command I was executing to test it locally.
 
`adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n <app_package>/<app_package>.x.y.InstallReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_medium%3Dpartner%26utm_campaign%3Dpartner_name"`

Comment: To verify the same I've created a sample application, and found INSTALL_REFERRER is still working as expected in Android 8.0. There is no impact of Android 8.0 (API level 26) Background Execution Limits. Thanks **Sagar** and **Dhananjay**.

Finally I have found the issue, issue was with command was missing correct package name.

Answer (score 1):

com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER is considered explicit intent by the definition of it. 
As per my understanding, there is nothing much changed for capturing INSTALL_REFERRER. Everything is as it was before.

Answer (score 1):

`INSTALL_REFERRER` would be considered as explicit intent, since it's app specific.

Also, this intent is not fired by system, but rather Google Play Services library.

So there shouldn't be any changes to its intended behavior on Android O